# Missing monitor content after locking a screen except coursor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I use on Thinkpad two external monitors, one is connected with HDMI, one is with DP -> USB-C. While the first one is working correctly, a second one behaves in a strange way after locking a computer.

When I'm leaving the computer in the office I use Windows+L to lock user account. In 90% cases when I come back I wake up the laptop and all monitors are working fine. In 10% cases I can see black screen on the second monitor.
In Settings -> Displays I can see all monitors correctly set up and when I move mouse on the second monitor I can see it - I also see I'm hovering over the text box as the cursor changes to text type, so looks like the content is there. The only question - why it's all black then and not visibile?

Current workaround is to restart a system, but for obvious reasons I'd like to find another way.

What I tried is to restart GNOME (`ALT+F2`, then `r` command) and disable energy saving mode.

Answer (score 0):

For future users, I think I fixed this issue by downgrade NVidia drivers and then reupgrading it.

Access to the drivers can be managed by `Software & Updates` in Ubuntu's default settings (can be reached by pressing `Super` key - which is usually a Windows key on the keyboard and typing `Software & Updates` - it should narrow amount of possible apps to this one only).

Then you need to navigate to `Additional drivers` tab, where by default I got listed all Drivers for my NVIDIA graphic card. I tried to install different ones (by selecting on the list and click `Apply Changes` button) but looks like `nvidia-driver-460` seems to be working.

Consider `sudo apt upgrade` anyway, always good to try

Comment: While this answer may provide a solution to the problem, It lacks instructions on how to fix the the problem. Please consider including more details.

Comment: Good point @stumblebee, I've edited a comment